# Search whole mySQL table for mulitple entereis from same MAC address

Tags: mysql, search, phpmyadmin, xampp

I need to search for number of entries a mac address makes in a database. Using xampp with MySQL database. When I do a search it will only search on the 500 that are showing (500 lines is maximum).

It is 149 pages of 500 entries in total. How can I search the whole 149 pages with one search to see all entries from a single mac address?

[mySQL Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A24nF.png)

Comment: uh, so basically you wish for the entire entry shown in a single page instead got paginated?

Comment: so basicaly I need to enter mac addess 002c (for example) and it will search through the whole 149 pages and show me each entry at the moment it will only search one page, not 149 pages (using xampp mySQL)

Comment: well, do you know what plain sql is..? you could do `SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE bracelet_mac = '002c'`. Nevertheless, your screenshot is `phpmyadmin` that shipped along in xampp.. (on how to enter raw query, just above your screenshot, there are several tabs right? find `SQL` and paste the sql query there. anyway, start [reading this sql tutorial - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) so, you got your basic covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this graphically from the "Search" tab, just enter the same search criteria like you would build an SQL command manually. In this case, you'd enter the entire MAC address or a portion of it and pick the search type that best matches the query you're looking to build.

[image: Search interface]